# method in server not reflected in web services client

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, eclipse-wtp

i created the simple webservice using eclipse and AXIS2 which works fine,
now i added one more method to the service it is not reflected in client.
is there any way to add that method other than creating the client again?

Answer (score 1):

You need to regenerate client.

Comment: in that case i will lose the prior used method in that client or i need to rewrite the old client code, sure there is no other way, i dont have any knowledge about contarct last in webservices  can i use it here

Comment: Hmmm, usually when you generate client code, you don't change it, but use the generated classes from your code. So you can regenerate code whenever you want.